# Imputed data: how to check residuals of the pooled analysis

Tags: r, linear-model, residuals, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I used mice (Multiple imputation by chained equations) to impute my dataset with missing variables. Next, I did a linear regression on the imputed datasets (m=50) and pooled the results according to Rubin's Rules.

However, I am not sure how should I now check the residuals. On each imputed dataset or is there a way to check the residuals for the pooled model?

Comment: Do either of these posts answer your question?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137209/multiple-imputation-and-regression-model-diagnostics   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548467/model-diagnostics-in-multiple-imputation/548871#548871

Comment: yes, thank you! this is what I was looking for!